# why is my datatable not showing data in page?

Tags: ajax, laravel-8

i am using datatable in adminLTE laravel8 and the table is not showing on the page

here my js script

```js
@push('js')
    
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loaddata()
    })

    function loaddata() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            serverside: true,
            processing: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{route('supplier.index')}}",
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: 'nama',
                    name: 'nama'
                },
                {
                    data: 'telp',
                    name: 'telp'
                },
                {
                    data: 'email',
                    name: 'email'
                },
                {
                    data: 'account',
                    name: 'account'
                },
                {
                    data: 'address',
                    name: 'address'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false
                },
            ]
        })
    }
</script>
@endpush('js')
```

data shows when I return json, but when I render in view it doesn't show,
the page is blank

please help me..

Comment: Where is the backend part? Add that in the code too. Maybe something is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines

Inside Head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
```

In footer section

```
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).